# When is the directional derivative of $f=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}$ equal to $|\nabla f|$ in the direction $\textbf{r}=(x,y,z)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I know that the directional derivative of the field f is:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\frac{2}{r}\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)$$

From this result I do not know how to work out when $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=|\nabla f|$.

I would be grateful for any help received.

Answer (score 0):

The directional derivative of a field is just $\nabla f\cdot \vec{u}$ in the direction of unit vector $\vec{u}$.

Thus the directional derivative of $f$ at $r$ is

$$2(\frac{x}{a^{2}}\hat{i}+\frac{y}{b^{2}}\hat{j}+\frac{z}{c^{2}}\hat{k})\cdot (\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}\hat{i}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}\hat{j}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}\hat{k})$$

In order to have quality between $|\nabla f|$ and the directional derivative you need to take the direction $\vec{r}$ to be parallel to the gradient $\nabla f$.
That is you take $\vec{r}=\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$ and then compute the directional derivative.

In otherwords , the directional derivative is maximum along the gradient of the field.